# jquery ui similar to Apple Finder

Tags: jquery-ui, macos, finder

I'm looking to build a navigation system similar to Apple Finder using jQuery UI.  The idea is you drag an object into this 'finder' navigation and are able to navigate between folders to drop an object.  This is to behave similar to moving a file from on your Desktop to a directory or moving a file between directories.

Additionally, inside this 'finder' navigation, I'd like to be able to sort objects by dragging and dropping using jQuery UI Sortable, except it will need to be a nested sortable option.

Has anything like this been created yet?  I prefer not to reinvent the wheel in javascript if necessary.  Otherwise, any examples or directions to help solve this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but you can see what I've done with jQuery Finder: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryfinder/ (the demo link does not work, so you'll have to checkout the trunk)

It's pretty much abandoned so I'd love it if someone else would pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is quite similar if you're still looking..
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress-sidebar-turned-apple-flashy-using-jquery-ui/